# Reading .xlsx format in python

Tags: python, excel, xlsx, openpyxl

I've got to read .xlsx file every 10min in python.
What is the most efficient way to do this?
I've tried using xlrd, but it doesn't read .xlsx - according to documentation he does, but I can't do this - getting `Unsupported format, or corrupt file` exceptions.
What is the best way to read xlsx?
I need to read comments in cells too.

Comment: According to [documentation of xlrd](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) it doesnt

Answer (score 8):

xlrd hasn't released the version yet to read xlsx.  Until then, [Eric Gazoni](http://ericgazoni.wordpress.com/2010/05/23/openpyxl-python-xlsx-1-0/) built a package called [openpyxl](https://bitbucket.org/ericgazoni/openpyxl/issues?milestone=1.1) - reads xlsx files, and does limited writing of them.

Comment: As of version 0.8.0 (August 2012), xlrd has been able to read .xlsx files.

Comment: Note: xlrd no longer supports xlsx at the time of writing.

Answer (score 5):

Use Openpyxl some basic examples:

```
import openpyxl

# Open Workbook
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='example.xlsx', data_only=True)

# Get All Sheets
a_sheet_names = wb.get_sheet_names()
print(a_sheet_names)

# Get Sheet Object by names
o_sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name("Sheet1")
print(o_sheet)

# Get Cell Values
o_cell = o_sheet['A1']
print(o_cell.value)

o_cell = o_sheet.cell(row=2, column=1)
print(o_cell.value)

o_cell = o_sheet['H1']
print(o_cell.value)

# Sheet Maximum filled Rows and columns
print(o_sheet.max_row)
print(o_sheet.max_column)
```

Comment: SO says "Suggested edit queue is full" so it'll have to be a comment:  
`wb.get_sheet_names()` has been depreacted in favor of `wb.sheetnames` and `wb.get_sheet_by_name("Sheet1")` has been deprecated in favor of `wb["Sheet1"]`

Answer (score 5):

There are [multiple ways to read XLSX formatted files using python](http://www.python-excel.org). Two are illustrated below and require that you install openpyxl at least and if you want to parse into pandas directly you want to install pandas, eg. `pip install pandas openpyxl`

**Option 1: pandas direct**

Primary use case: load just the data for further processing.

Using [read_excel()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) function in pandas would be your best choice. Note that pandas should fall back to openpyxl automatically but in the event of format issues its best to specify the engine directly.

```
df_pd = pd.read_excel("path/file_name.xlsx", engine="openpyxl")
```

**Option 2 - openpyxl direct**

Primary use case: getting or editing specific Excel document elements such as comments (requested by OP), formatting properties or formulas.

Using [load_workbook()](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html) followed by comment extraction using the [comment attribute](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/comments.html) for each cell would be achieved by the following.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename = "path/file_name.xlsx")
ws = wb.active
ws["A1"].comment # <- loop through row & columns to extract all comments
```

Comment: One distinction that might be relevant is for cases that the .xlsx contains formulas.

pd.read_excel() provides the values which result from the formulas.

openpyxl.load_workbook() provides the formulas as a string.

Maybe this behavior is configurable, with openpyxl or pandas, not sure.